# Term for someone who is straight and cisgendered?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a value-neutral term to refer to someone who is heterosexual and cisgendered. I haven't run into a convenient one that didn't imply something positive or negative about the gender/sexuality combination.

Actually, considering the nuances of definitions within the LBGTQ community, I should clarify that there are a few slightly different groups, any of which I would be happy to have a term for, or different terms for each of them.  I'd be happy to have any term that would appropriately describe any of these three slightly different groups:

1. Someone who is cisgendered and heterosexual
2. Someone who is straight and cisgendered but not heterosexual (such as someone who is heteroromantic but asexual)
3. Someone that wouldn't be considered to fit under any part of the LBGTQ+ umbrella, so for instance a term that would not include a hetero/cis person who was aromantic or intersexed.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62454/discussion-on-question-by-dsollen-term-for-someone-who-is-straight-and-cisgender).